# Showing subspaces are equal if sum is equal to one of the subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space with $W_1$ and $W_2$ as its subspaces, I want to show 
$$
W_1=W_1 + W_2 \Leftrightarrow W_1=W_2.
$$
I can show one side but I am having trouble proving 
$$
W_1 + W_2 \Rightarrow W_1=W_2.
$$

Comment: Well, it's not true.  Suppose $W_2=\{0\}$ and $W_1$ is the whole space, for instance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you forget to type "$W1=$" after the word "proving"$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality is wrong. If we have $W_1$ a 2-dimensional vector subspace and $W_2 \subset W_1$, then $W_1+W_2=W_1\neq W_2$. What we can show is :

$$W_1=W_1+W_2 \iff W_2 \subseteq W_1$$

$\implies$ : Any linear combinations of $W_1+W_2$ are in $W_1$. If there was a vector $v$ in $W_2$ but not in $W_1$, that would contradict that fact.

$\impliedby$: Any linear combination of vectors in $W_2$ and $W_1$ is in fact a combination of vectors in $W_1$, so by the definition of a vector subspace then it is contained in $W_1$

You just have to formalize a bit more but that's the idea.